# Model->validates() doesn't appear to be working

Tags: cakephp

I'm currently using cakephp 2.4.5 and having an issue with Model::validates(). For some reason it's not working... Here is a sample of what's happening:

Controller:

```
$this->Transaction->create();
$this->Transaction->set($this->request->data);

if ($this->Transaction->validates()) {
    if (!$this->Transaction->save($this->request->data)) {
        //why is this happening, how is it possible????
        pr($this->Transaction->validationErrors);
    }   
} else {
    $this->Session->setFlash('validation failed');
}
```

View:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Transaction');?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Address.address'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('amount'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('User.password'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Submit')); ?>
```

In the view, the only error messages being displayed are for the address and amount, the password validations error's aren't displayed...

```
pr($this->Transaction->validationErrors);
Array
(
    [Address] => Array
        (
            [address] => Array
                (
                    [0] => The address you provided does not appear to be valid. Please try again.
                )

        )

    [User] => Array
        (
            [password] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Your password must be between 6 and 12 characters in length.
                )

        )

)
```

Any ideas? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "it's not working", but I did notice one thing. When I manually call validation I use an equality comparison. Also, do not create a new entry for transaction until it's been validated. I'm not sure if that would cause errors, but regardless, you don't want it to create an entry if the input doesn't pass validation.

```
if ($this->Transaction->validates() == true){
    $this->Transaction->create(); //this goes after the validation, not before
```

> In the view, the only error messages being displayed are for the address and amount, the password validations error's aren't displayed...

**edit** The validation seems to be selecting from only one model. Try validating the models separately

```
if($this->Transaction->validates() == true){
   $this->loadmodel('User'); //assuming you don't arleady have it loaded
   if($this->User->validates(array('fieldList' => array('password'))) == true) {
```

Comment: I tried with $this->Transaction->validates() == true but still no dice. It seems that the only actual validation is occuring in the Model::save() method.

Comment: I also tried User.abc (just as a test to make sure that the Auth component wasn't doing something screwy) but the validation errors still don't display for that either.

Comment: @user3251563 try using $this->Model-saveField('table.row_name', $value) for each of your fields. You'll at least be able to see which ones are saving. You'll also see if the password is hashing.  You'll have to create an entry, then get the ID ($this->Model->getLastInsertID()). Then set that ID ($this->model->id = $id) and do the saveField thing I mentioned.

Comment: The problem really occurs before I even get that far. If i input invalid data in the form and then do an if ($this->Transaction->validates()) { //this should be false, but it's evaluating as true }

Comment: @user3251563 try validating your models separately and only validate the password for the user model. I added an example to my post.

Comment: That gets me another step further. Any idea on why the validation errors wouldn't display in the view (form helper) though?

Comment: @user3251563 I'm guessing it's due to the naming of the form and selecting from multiple models. Try placing all of the validation in your transaction model. If you do this don't reference the table in your form. So it'll just be 'password' and 'address'. Not 'User.password' and 'Address.address'